# Harmonic Conjugates

Tags: complex-analysis

In Gamelin it is stated that "[t]he basis for application of Green's theorem to harmonic functions is the following important observation.

**Lemma.** *If $u(x, y)$ is harmonic, then the differential*

$\hspace{2in} -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$d$x + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$d$y$

*is closed.*"

What does Gamelin mean by "closed" here?

I found a definition of "closed surface" in the "Dictionary of Analysis, Calculus, and Differential Equations," which states that a closed surface is "[a] surface that has no boundary curves [and] can be characterized as a connected compact metric space in which every point has a neighborhood that is homeomorphic with the interior of a circle." The former part seems to connect with a discussion at Paul's Online Math Notes:

$\hspace{2in}$[image: graphic1],

where it is mentioned that "[a]round the edge of [the above] surface we have a curve C.  This curve is called the boundary curve." Also, just by considering the function $u(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$ the defined differential, say d$g$ for instance, produces $g(x, y) = 4xy + C$:

$\hspace{2in}$ [image: graphic2],

which appears to have no boundary curve, but, perhaps, I have the notion mixed up.

OK, now I see that the author just meant "closed differential form."

$\hspace{2in}$ [image: www]

Thank you Gerry Myerson and Christopher A. Wong for pointing this out (see below).

Comment: $\phi$ is a closed differential form means $d\phi=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author is referring to a much larger mathematical concept from differential geometry: a differential $\sigma$ is called *closed* if $d\sigma = 0$, where $d$ denotes the *exterior derivative*.

However, you're taking a course on complex analysis, so this is probably not the answer you're looking to hear. In your case, we should think of the differential
$$ \sigma = -u_y dx + u_x dy$$
as a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$ with components $(-u_y, u_x,0)$ (or you can think of this simply as a 2d vector field), and the exterior derivative  goes by the more familiar name *curl*. Indeed, if you check the curl of this vector field, you obtain $(0,0,u_{xx} + u_{yy})$, so if $u$ is harmonic, then the vector field is irrotational (zero curl).

Given this, now you hopefully see the connection to Green's theorem, as the theorem connects the line integral of a vector field to its curl.

Comment: Thank you, Christopher A. Wong.